# duel regression with orthogonal constraints on coefficients

Tags: regression, linear-algebra, total-least-squares, linear-programming

I'm trying to solve a problem where I need to find two deming style regression models onto two different data sets of equal dimension who's coefficients(A,B) satisfy the following criteria with respect to a third model (C).

A dot C + B dot C =0

I'm really not even sure where to begin with a problem like this, I'm pretty sure it's got a direct analytical solution at least and I looked into linear programming but I can't seem to find a direction to tackle it in python.

Comment: Please describe your data: how one goes about fitting such models depends on characterizing the probabilistic or random elements and their relationships.